# Unable To Make MicroServo99 SG90 spin with raspberry pi

Tags: python, pwm, servo

I am having an issue with my raspberry pi and making it spin a motor with python. I am currently using a battery connected to a PCA9685 16-Channel 12-bit PWM driver which connects my motor on channel 0 to my raspberry pi. I am using to LI-ION ERC 18650 300mAh (3.7v and they are charged to 4.1 right now) batteries to power it as well as my raspberry pi being connected to the wall. I originally thought the issue was with the batteries being dead, so I charged them over night. This fixed nothing, and now I am not sure. Here is my code.

```
import time
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit

kit = ServoKit(channels=16, address=0x40)  # Initialize the ServoKit object

servo_channel = 0  # Specify the channel number to control the servo

def move_servo(angle):
   kit.servo[servo_channel].angle = angle
   time.sleep(0.1)

# Example usage: Move the servo to 90 degrees
move_servo(90)
```

Does anyone know where my issue is? Thanks!
Note: This is a 360 motor, not a 180

Comment: sorry, issue with copy and pasting. fixing right now

Comment: Connect the servo direct to the Pi and use pigs to send servo pulses.  Get that working first. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#S/SERVO